# Why doesn't enabling the rtc interrupt show in the /proc/interrupts?

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, real-time

I've written a simple app to enable rtc interrupts.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/rtc.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>   

int main() {
    int fd = open("/dev/rtc0",O_RDONLY);
    int hz = 64;

    if (ioctl(fd, RTC_IRQP_SET, hz) == -1){
        printf("ioctl(RTC_IRQP_SET) failed");
        return 1;
    }    
    if (ioctl(fd, RTC_PIE_ON) == -1){
        printf("ioctl(RTC_PIE_ON) failed");
        return 1;
    }    
}
```

After its run, I was expecting the interrupts to show up in `/proc/interrupts` under IRQ8.

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt:

> However it can also be used to generate signals from a slow 2Hz to a
>   relatively fast 8192Hz, in increments of powers of two. These signals
>   are reported by interrupt number 8. (Oh! So *that* is what IRQ 8 is
>   for...) It can also function as a 24hr alarm, raising IRQ 8 when the
>   alarm goes off.

But there was no change. The

`8:          0          1   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0`

remained passive. What am I missing here?

Comment: Good question! Interestingly, if you put in the `char buf[8]; for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))` the program takes 1s as expected. So it's working, but the interrupt still isn't counted.

Comment: Did you read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). You don't need RTC to get time!

Comment: Show the entire `/proc/interrupts`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that periodic interrupts (PIE) are implemented using a timer or hrtimer (depending on your machine), not the RTC. You can have a look at:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/rtc/interface.c#L574 and
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/rtc.c#L445

Basically, you will only get an interrupt when you set an alarm.